# Growth and multiplication of $p$-adic formal power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose that we can factor a formal power series $f\in\mathbb{Q}_p[[ X]]$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=g(x)h(x)
\end{equation*}
where $g,h\in\mathbb{Q}_p[[X]]$. In addition, we have the following growth conditions on the coefficients of $f$ and $g$:
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\frac{|a_n|_p}{n^\alpha}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\hspace{1cm} \text{ and }\hspace{1cm} \left\{\frac{|b_n|_p}{n^\alpha}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty
\end{equation*}
are bounded sequences (as sequences in $\mathbb{R}$). *Edit: Any smaller value of $\alpha$, say $\alpha^*$, will make the sequences unbounded.

**Prove or Disprove: $h$ has bounded coefficients.** I am hoping this is something we can prove, but I'm not sure if it's possible in full generality. To simplify the matter, you may assume that $\alpha=1$.

To clarify
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_nx^n\\
g(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_nx^n\\
h(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_nx^n
\end{align*}

Comment: It's hard to come up with a sequence $(a_n)_n$ like that. My guess is that this isn't true and you can make an example of the form $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $g(x) = (p-x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

Comment: Try $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. This sequence satisfies the conditions for $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Hmm you're right, I guess it isn't as hard as I thought. In that case I think you have your counterexample since $b_n = \frac{p}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1}$ should also satisfy the conditions?